# Cohomology via simplicial homotopy theory and its relation to completion

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm reading a [Bousfield and Kan's](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/bk-yellow.pdf) book and I'm curious could homotopical approach to homology be extended to cohomology?

I will elaborate a bit: homology with coefficients in commutative ring $R$ could be defined using homotopy groups of certain simplicial set ($R$-module to be precise):
$$\widetilde{H}_*(X;R)=\pi_*(R \otimes X/R\otimes pt)$$
where $R$ is regarded as a simplicial module and $X$ is a simplicial set by default.

So my question here is could we define cohomology in a similar way? And if we can (which I am almost sure of) how this definition would interact with the machinery of completions and localizations developed by [Bousfield and Kan](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/bk-yellow.pdf)?

My guess is that we should take something like $\widetilde{H}^*(X)=\pi_*($Hom$(X;R)/$Hom$(pt;R))$ under previous assumptions.

---

UPD: following remarks by Connor Malin I should clarify that $X$ here is a *pointed* simplicial set.

$R\otimes X$ is a "free simplicial $R$-module" generated by $X$ (i.e. $(R\otimes X)_n$ is a free $R$-module generated by $n$-simplices of $X$ with face and degeneracy operators induced from X).

Comment: What does $R \otimes X$ mean here when $X$ is just a simplicial set? Does it mean the free $R$ module on $X$?

Comment: Yes, $R\otimes X$ is a simplicial module with the structure of the free module on X in each dimension. $(R\otimes X)_n=R\langle X_n\rangle,$ where $R\langle X_n\rangle$ denotes a free module generated by $n$-simplices of X.

Answer (score 2):

I assume since you are using reduced cohomology that your $X$ is pointed. In this case it is true that $\bar{H}^k(X)=\pi_0(Hom(X,S^k R))$, where $S^k$ denotes shifting the chain complex up $k$ indices, because cohomology is represented by $K(R,*)$ and $S^k R$ by Dold-Kan has its homotopy group $R$ in dimension $k$ and $0$ elsewhere. Taking higher homotopy groups of this space just gives us lower cohomology groups.

Comment: Thank you for the definition, but I was also interested in the way this object will behave under completion. For example, is it true that cohomology of $R$-completion is cohomology with coefficients in $R$ for $R$-good spaces?